# latex large division sign in a math formula

Tags: latex

I have been looking for an answer for some time now, hope you could give me a quick tip.

I have an equation with many divisions inside. i.e:

```
$\frac{\frac{a_1}{a_2}} {\frac{b_1}{b_2}}$
```

To make it more readable, I decided to change the large fraction into "/" sign. i.e.

```
$\frac{a_1}{a_2} / \frac{b_1}{b_2}$
```

The problem is that the "/" sign remains small, and it is quite ugly.

How do I change the "/" sign to have a big font? How do I make it more readable?

Comment: Can this get moved to tex.stackexchange.com ?  It'd be on topic there.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Another option is to use \dfrac instead of \frac, which makes the whole fraction larger and hence more readable.

And no, I don't know if there is an option to get something in between \frac and \dfrac, sorry.

Comment: Is there a way to make the equation somewhere between \frac and \dfrac ? - When I use \dfrac the equation is 4 lines long, which is a bit too much.

Answer (score 45):

I found the answer I was looking for.
The thing to use here is the construct of

```
\left \middle \right
```

For example, in this case, two possible solutions are:

```
$\left( {\frac{a_1}{a_2}} \middle/ {\frac{b_1}{b_2}} \right) $
```

Or, in case the brackets are not necessary:

```
$\left. {\frac{a_1}{a_2}} \middle/ {\frac{b_1}{b_2}} \right. $
```

Comment: Looks like this will only work in an extended version eTeX or eLaTeX.

Comment: @Alexey, I think that I have a basic version of latex, with nothing special, and it works for me. Actually, I'm not sure how I can check which version I have.

Comment: No need to check the version. Works for you? fine! I have read TeXbook written by Donald Knuth, and was surprised to see the new macro. I started to look for more details on the Internet. I found that there is expansion of TeX. +1

Answer (score 22):

A possible soluttion that requires tweaking, but is very flexible is to use one of `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`,`\Bigg` in front of your division sign - these will make it progressively larger. For your formula, I think

```
  $\frac{a_1}{a_2} \Big/ \frac{b_1}{b_2}$
```

looks nicer than `\middle\` which is automatically sized and IMHO is a bit too large.

Comment: Thanks, because `\middle/` did not work for me (LaTeXIt, version 2015)

Comment: Is there anything larger than `/` but smaller than `\big/`? Both sizes appear in this [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9AFl.png). Using Jupyter built-in MathML, not sure it follows all standards.